# Stuck to hair / stuck in hair

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

I have an error spotting question.

> She was annoyed (A)/ when she found that (b) / the chewing gum was stuck to her hair. (C) / No error .

My book says it is error free but I think there is an error in **C** part , It should be stuck **in** her hair . I googled for general sentences with these keywords ( chewing gum , stuck , hair ) All sentences which I found were ***stuck in hair*** .  So Am I correct ? Or we can use both **in** and **to** here ?

Comment: You can have brambles stuck in your hair and gum stuck to your hair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where the gum was stuck.

> stuck **to** hair

[image]

usually means something is sitting *on top of* the hair, whereas

> stuck **in** hair

means it is intertwined *with* the hair

[image]
<sub>(source: [popsugar-assets.com](https://media1.popsugar-assets.com/files/thumbor/B-GfdVPwinIAxK3E9j4_0F2rcpM/fit-in/1024x1024/filters:format_auto-!!-:strip_icc-!!-/2015/11/23/719/n/24155406/84f320ed0ab3e026_Screen_Shot_2015-11-23_at_10.53.16_AM/i/Parents-Angry-Bunchems-Toy-Geting-Stuck-Kids-Hair.png))</sub>
[image]

For example,

> Shampoo is first applied **onto** your hair and then worked **into** your hair.

[image]

Comment: The shower picture is worthy of a Hitchcock knockoff, where the psychotic is the one **in** the shower.